# Using GPU to run python script in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, gpu, nvidia

I am trying to run the following python script from my anaconda prompt:

```
python object_tracker.py --video test.mp4 --model yolov4 --dont_show
```

This comes directly from the AI Guys yolov4-deepsort repository (https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort). It is code for an object tracker so its very computation heavy and running it on longer videos take hours. A computer with and Nvidia Graphics card has become available to me and I want to use GPU to speed up the process but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

Python OpenCV uses NumPy for computation and NumPy runs on CPU. You can convert NumPy arrays to Pytorch tensors and can run your code on GPU. A simple idea is

```py
N = 8000
np.random.seed(42)
nA = np.random.rand(N,N).astype(np.float32)
nB = np.random.rand(N,N).astype(np.float32)
nC = nA.dot(nB) # numpy dot product runs on CPU

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
print(f'PyTorch set to {device}') # cuda when available

tA = torch.from_numpy(nA).float().to(device)
tB = torch.from_numpy(nB).to(device)
tC = torch.mm(tA,tB) # torch matrix multiplication aka dot product runs on GPU
```

PS:

Just came across this

https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-torchvision-functionalities-for-pytorch-391273299dc9

seems you can do it in a better way with torchvision.